# Read JSON Node from passed in string

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js

I'm trying to centralize endpoints to a single JSON file in my api folder.

```
{ 
  EndPoint: {
     Action: {
        path1: '/thisispath1/{id}',
        path2: '/thisispath2/',
     }
}
```

What I want to do is get the path name kinda of like how useTranslations works.

```
    const t = useTranslations('Endpoint');
    const path = t('Acton.path1',1);
//path = '/thisispath1/1';
```

Not sure where to start with this.

It some what worked with the top level node.
i.e.
`GetEndpoint('EndPoint');`
returns

```
     Action: {
        path1: '/thisispath1/{id}',
        path2: '/thisispath2/',
     }
```

but not
`GetEndpoint('EndPoint.Action.path1',1);`
returns undefined

```
type EndPointKeys = keyof typeof endPoints;

export const GetEndPoint = (action: string, parameter: string) => {

//Think I have to a recursive keyof typeof here?

    return endPoints[action as keyof typeof endPoints];

};
```

What I ended doing:

```
import endPoints from '../service-end-points/service-constants.json';

const jsonPathToValue = (Points: any, path: string) => {

    let jsonData = Points;
    let newpath = path.replace(/\[(\w+)\]/g, '.$1'); // convert indexes to properties
    newpath = newpath.replace(/^\./, ''); // strip a leading dot
    const pathArray = newpath.split('.');
    let key = '';
    for (let i = 0; i <= pathArray.length; i++) {
        key = pathArray[i];
        if (key in jsonData) {
            if (jsonData[key as keyof typeof jsonData] !== null) {
                jsonData = jsonData[key as keyof typeof endPoints];
            }
        }
    }
    const finalPath = pathArray.slice(-1)[0];
    try {
        if (jsonData?.Actions[finalPath]) {
            return jsonData?.Actions[finalPath];
        }
    } catch (e) {
        return null;
    }
};

export const GetEndPoint = (path: string) => {
    const url = jsonPathToValue(endPoints, path);
    const HOST = process.env.CONSTELLATION_SERVICE_URL || null;
    if (!HOST) {
        throw new Error('SERVICE HOST NOT DEFINED');
    }
    return `${HOST}${url}`;
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In fact, what you want is **convert a string t a JSON path**.
You can check this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27628573/how-to-convert-a-string-to-jsonpath) it should answer your question.

You will have some different solutions to solve that.

Comment: Thanks - link seems broken.  Found [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27628573/how-to-convert-a-string-to-jsonpath) is that it?

Comment: Just repaired the link, yes exactly, here you have some solutions for your problem

Comment: Got it working!  Had to do an extra step of: 
        ```if (jsonData?.Actions[finalPath]) {
            return jsonData?.Actions[finalPath];
        }```
and add some types for typescript. 

Thanks again for your help.

Comment: yes you had to check if variable are null or not you can put answer as accepted if this solution fit for you.